How to add OpenTelemetry for .NET framework applications hosted in IIS?
I am trying to add OpenTelemetry for .NET framework applications hosted in IIS using https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation?tab=readme-ov-file documentation while checking the log files I can see lots of similar errors.
Code:
$appPools = Get-IISAppPool
$appPoolNames = $appPools.Name
$appPoolNames.Count

foreach($appPoolName in $appPoolNames)
{
    if($appPoolName -ne "DefaultAppPool")
    {
        $appcmd = "$($env:systemroot)\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe"
        $appPool = $appPoolName
        
        $environment = @{
            OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES="name=$appPool,service.version=1.0.0"
            OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=$appPool
            COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1
            COR_PROFILER="{918728DD-259F-4A6A-AC2B-B85E1B658318}"
            COR_PROFILER_PATH_64="C:\Program Files\opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation-windows\win-x64\OpenTelemetry.AutoInstrumentation.Native.dll"
            OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_HOME="C:\Program Files\opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation-windows"
            OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=<URL>
            OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_TRACES_CONSOLE_EXPORTER_ENABLED="true"
            OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_METRICS_CONSOLE_EXPORTER_ENABLED="true"
            OTEL_DOTNET_AUTO_LOGS_CONSOLE_EXPORTER_ENABLED="true"
        }

        $environment.Keys | ForEach-Object {
          & $appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+"[name='$appPool'].environmentVariables.[name='$_',value='$($environment[$_])']"
        }
    }
}

Error:
EventSource=OpenTelemetry-AutoInstrumentation, Message=The profiler has been initialized with 0 derived definitions. 
EventSource=OpenTelemetry-Api, Message=Failed to inject activity context in format: 'TraceContextPropagator', context: 'Invalid context'.

Could anyone help me to fix it or suggest solution.

Please check here to see if similar issues have been reported and resolved.  https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet-instrumentation/issues
